# SQL : Check if result = number for each id

Tags: sql

I have this sort of structure

```
ID    STATUS
1     FIRSTSTAT
2     FIRSTSTAT
3     FIRSTSTAT
1     SECSTAT
3     SECSTAT
3     THIRDSTAT
3     FOURTHSTAT
3     FIFTHSTAT
```

I want to get the `3` back because he has all following status (FIRSTSTAT, SECSTAT, THIRDSTAT). Do you have an idea how I could make that?

It should be done by explicitely giving the statuses because other statuses exist so `SELECT FROM WHERE = 'THIRDSTAT'` is not ok since it should have all three statuses, not only one of them.

So I guess it should be done calculating the SUM or something like that.

I tried the following but of course, it does not work :

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
AND
AND
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of different status values is known to always be 3:

```
select id
from tablename
where status in ('FIRSTSTAT', 'SECSTAT', 'THIRDSTAT')
group by id
having count(distinct status) = 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :). I'm afraid this wouldn't work because other statuses exist. So I should name explicitely FIRSTSTAT, SECSTAT and THIRDSTAT. Do you know an other way maybe?

Comment: @YassinHajaj: then you need a `where status in (...)` to the first query and list the three status values you are interested in (but you should have mentioned that in your question, that you have more then three status shown in your sample data)

Comment: why in the world it wouldn't work just because other statuses exist? in technical sense the script made "works"..I can't understand where the "wouldn't work" is coming from..

Comment: This query answers your question, AFAIK

Comment: @YassinHajaj, add some FOURTHSTAT to the sample data.

Comment: @YassinHajaj it seems you're satisfied with the answer. What if the "where status in ('FIRSTSTAT','THIRDSTAT')" has been specified? what Id are you expecting to return?

Comment: @kenlacoste That's not my goal. I need to have the id having these three statuses. Or maybe I don't understand your question...